# Weblogic 10.3.6 Error With SharedLibrary Unresolved Webapp Library references

Tags: weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a shared library as a webapp and have access to the libraries there reciden from another webapp.

My application server is WebLogic 10.3.6, my jdk is 1.6 JRockit

My WebApp with shared libraries is called clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war and is generated with maven.

within that webapp, in the META-INF directory I created the MANIFEST.MF file which contains the following:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: Common libraries Clares
Specification-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Common libraries Clares
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Extension-Name: clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

when ant deploy this webapp via the log he says:

K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares>ant deploy_shared
Buildfile: build.xml

```
        deploy_shared:
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer -debug -remote -verbose -upload -noexit -name clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -source K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_shared\target\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -password ******** -deploy -library
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -remote -verbose -upload -noexit -name clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -source K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_shared\target\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy -library
     [wldeploy] [WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>():115] : Constructing DeploymentManager for J2EE version V1_4 deployments
     [wldeploy] [WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection():158] : Connecting to admin server at localhost:7001, as user weblogic
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():286] : setting environment
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():289] : getting context using t3://localhost:7001
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():237] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():237] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
     [wldeploy] [DomainManager.resetDomain():36] : Getting new domain
     [wldeploy] [DomainManager.resetDomain():39] : Using pending domain: false
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@a1bbe4
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@a1bbe4
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@a33ce3
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@a33ce3
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.initialize():169] : Connected to WLS domain: CLARES_base_domain
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.setRemote():480] : Running in remote mode
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.init():159] : Initializing ServerConnection : weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl@cfd032
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():713] : Incoming tmids:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():715] :   {Target=AdminServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT}, targeted=true
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.deriveAppName():141] : appname established as: clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
     [wldeploy] <19-ago-2016 09H32' CLT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [archive: K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_shared\target\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war], to AdminServer .>
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():713] : Incoming tmids:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():715] :   {Target=AdminServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT}, targeted=true
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.loadGeneralOptions():628] : Delete Files:false
     [wldeploy] Timeout :3600000
     [wldeploy] Targets:
     [wldeploy] AdminServer
     [wldeploy] ModuleTargets={}
     [wldeploy] SubModuleTargets={}
     [wldeploy] }
     [wldeploy] Files:
     [wldeploy] null
     [wldeploy] Deployment Plan: null
     [wldeploy] App root: C:\Users\ODONAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\odonatafly\.\config\deployments\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
     [wldeploy] App config: C:\Users\ODONAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\odonatafly\.\config\deployments\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\plan
     [wldeploy] Deployment Options: {isRetireGracefully=true,isGracefulProductionToAdmin=false,isGracefulIgnoreSessions=false,rmiGracePeriod=-1,retireTimeoutSecs=-1,undeployAllVersions=false,archiveVersion=null,planVersion=null,isLibrary=true,libSpecVersion=null,libImplVersion=null,stageMode=null,clusterTimeout=3600000,altDD=null,altWlsDD=null,name=clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT,securityModel=null,securityValidationEnabled=false,versionIdentifier=null,isTestMode=false,forceUndeployTimeout=0,defaultSubmoduleTargets=true,timeout=0,deploymentPrincipalName=null,useExpiredLock=false}
     [wldeploy]
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.upload():849] : Uploaded app to C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\CLARES_base_domain\.\servers\AdminServer\upload\clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():445] : Initiating deploy operation for app, clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, on targets:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():447] :    AdminServer
     [wldeploy] Task 50 initiated: [Deployer:149117]deploy library clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on AdminServer.
     [wldeploy] Task 50 completed: [Deployer:149117]deploy library clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on AdminServer.
     [wldeploy] Target state: deploy completed on Server AdminServer
     [wldeploy]
     [wldeploy] Target Assignments:
     [wldeploy] + clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT  AdminServer
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.close():332] : Closing DM connection
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.close():352] : Unregistered all listeners
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():372] : Closed JMX connection
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():384] : Closed Runtime JMX connection
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():396] : Closed Edit JMX connection
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

[Weblogic Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvZ68.png)

The webapp from which I want to access the SharedLibrary is called:

clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war

is created with maven and the weblogic.xml file have the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"> 
      <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
      </container-descriptor>
      <library-ref>
          <library-name>clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</library-name>
          <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
          <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
          <exact-match>false</exact-match>
      </library-ref>
    </weblogic-web-app>
```

when I try to deploy this webapp (clares_web) says the following error:

K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares>ant deploy_web
Buildfile: build.xml

```
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer -debug -verbose -noexit -name clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -source K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_web\target\clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -password ******** -deploy
     [wldeploy] weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -debug -verbose -noexit -name clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -source K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_web\target\clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war -targets AdminServer -adminurl t3://localhost:7001 -user weblogic -deploy
     [wldeploy] [WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.<init>():115] : Constructing DeploymentManager for J2EE version V1_4 deployments
     [wldeploy] [WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection():158] : Connecting to admin server at localhost:7001, as user weblogic
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():286] : setting environment
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getEnvironment():289] : getting context using t3://localhost:7001
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():237] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.getMBeanServer():237] : Connecting to MBeanServer at service:jmx:t3://localhost:7001/jndi/weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime
     [wldeploy] [DomainManager.resetDomain():36] : Getting new domain
     [wldeploy] [DomainManager.resetDomain():39] : Using pending domain: true
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@a07de5
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.TargetCache@a07de5
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():96] : Adding notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@a1ffa6
     [wldeploy] [MBeanCache.addNotificationListener():103] : Added notification listener for weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.mbeans.ModuleCache@a1ffa6
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.initialize():169] : Connected to WLS domain: CLARES_base_domain
     [wldeploy] [ServerConnectionImpl.init():159] : Initializing ServerConnection : weblogic.deploy.api.spi.deploy.internal.ServerConnectionImpl@d2f9ac
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():713] : Incoming tmids:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():715] :   {Target=AdminServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT}, targeted=true
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.deriveAppName():141] : appname established as: clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
     [wldeploy] <19-ago-2016 09H43' CLT> <Info> <J2EE Deployment SPI> <BEA-260121> <Initiating deploy operation for application, clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT [archive: K:\Development\CLA_RES\clares\clares_web\target\clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war], to AdminServer .>
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():713] : Incoming tmids:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.dumpTmids():715] :   {Target=AdminServer, WebLogicTargetType=server, Name=clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT}, targeted=true
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.loadGeneralOptions():628] : Delete Files:false
     [wldeploy] Timeout :3600000
     [wldeploy] Targets:
     [wldeploy] AdminServer
     [wldeploy] ModuleTargets={}
     [wldeploy] SubModuleTargets={}
     [wldeploy] }
     [wldeploy] Files:
     [wldeploy] null
     [wldeploy] Deployment Plan: null
     [wldeploy] App root: C:\Users\ODONAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\odonatafly\.\config\deployments\clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
     [wldeploy] App config: C:\Users\ODONAT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\odonatafly\.\config\deployments\clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\plan
     [wldeploy] Deployment Options: {isRetireGracefully=true,isGracefulProductionToAdmin=false,isGracefulIgnoreSessions=false,rmiGracePeriod=-1,retireTimeoutSecs=-1,undeployAllVersions=false,archiveVersion=null,planVersion=null,isLibrary=false,libSpecVersion=null,libImplVersion=null,stageMode=null,clusterTimeout=3600000,altDD=null,altWlsDD=null,name=clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT,securityModel=null,securityValidationEnabled=false,versionIdentifier=null,isTestMode=false,forceUndeployTimeout=0,defaultSubmoduleTargets=true,timeout=0,deploymentPrincipalName=null,useExpiredLock=false}
     [wldeploy]
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():445] : Initiating deploy operation for app, clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, on targets:
     [wldeploy] [BasicOperation.execute():447] :    AdminServer
     [wldeploy] Task 51 initiated: [Deployer:149026]deploy application clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on AdminServer.
     [wldeploy] dumping Exception stack
     [wldeploy] Task 51 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT on AdminServer.
     [wldeploy] Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
     [wldeploy] weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "ServletContext@806038954[app:clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT module:clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war path:/clares_web-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT spec-version:2.5]", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: clares_shared-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Specification-Version: 1, Implementation-Version: 8.1, exact-match: false]
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processWebAppLibraries(WebAppServletContext.java:2750)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:416)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:47)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:749)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
     [wldeploy]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

someone can help me to know what is the mistake I am making

thanxs

Gos

```
enter code here
```

Comment: what is the error message obtained in WLS console ?

Comment: i resolve my problem generating MANIFEST.MF in maven and it's oks, thanxs !!!!