# wldeploy ant task timeout value not in seconds

Tags: deployment, ant, weblogic

According to Oracle's Weblogic [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLPRG/wldeploy.htm#WLPRG435)

The timeout attribute for the wldeploy task states that the value is in seconds, specifically it reads "timeout ... The maximum number of seconds to wait for a deployment to succeed ... int", but when I set this value to 100, my task times out.  It continues to timeout until I set it to 100,000

Also another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041253/weblogic-10-3-6-error-with-sharedlibrary-unresolved-webapp-library-references?s=1|0.5291) mentions that the value is set to 3,600,000 which sounds like a lot of seconds to wait...

I have a feeling that this value is in milliseconds and the documentation is incorrect.  Can anyone confirm this?